# Is it possible to read head tracking data from Pixel Buds Pro?

Tags: android, audio, spatial

The latest firmware updates on Pixel Buds pro have enabled head tracking for spatial audio. Do you know if Google offers an API in Android to read data from the PixelBuds IMU (i.e. angles/orientation data) like Apple does for AirPods (CoreMotion API)?

I imagine it would be via Android's Sensors HAL API but I haven't found anything for reading this data in the documentation.

Besides, do you know if via the spatializer of Android 13

```
ro.audio.spatializer_enabled=true
```

it is possible to fix the position of a sound source?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Android offers the [Spatial Audio API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/spatial-audio) which documents all the ways to integrate spatial audio in your app, including how to integrate head tracking using the Pixel Buds Pro. It also *implies* that head tracking might only work using Pixel phones. Other android 13 devices might work, but there's no way of knowing unless the OEM declares it.

The android open source project documents the procedure for OEMs to adopt spatial audio into their flows, so it looks like it's up to them to actually adopt support.

There is actually scope for getting the raw sensor data using `Sensor.TYPE_HEAD_TRACKER` - see [here for documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_HEAD_TRACKER). BUT the docs ominously say:

> Note that this sensor type is typically not available for apps to use.

…and I tried it and it doesn't work (although I wasn't using a Pixel device).

Currently it looks like it's wedded to you

- Using Pixel Buds Pro
- Using Pixel Pro devices (The A series don't work)
- Using ExoPlayer to render the spatialised audio content

I really hope this opens up soon – at the moment it's as closed as Apple's APIs, although at least they provide a decent API for getting the movement data.

Comment: I was looking for the same... hopefully Android will open up... also discovered that Apple has CMHeadphoneMotionManager to do it... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmheadphonemotionmanager